# Which one of these PHP and Mysql scripts is safer security wise?

Tags: php, mysql

Is script 1 safer?

```
";
 }
 else
 {
  queryMysql("CREATE TABLE $name($query)");
  echo "Table '$name' created
";
 }
}

function tableExists($name)
{
 $result = queryMysql("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$name'");
 return mysql_num_rows($result);
}

function queryMysql($query)
{
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 return $result;
}

function destroySession()
{
 $_SESSION=array();

 if (session_id() != "" || isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]))
     setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-2592000, '/');

 session_destroy();
}

function sanitizeString($var)
{
 $var = strip_tags($var);
 $var = htmlentities($var);
 $var = stripslashes($var);
 return mysql_real_escape_string($var);
}

function showProfile($user)
{
 if (file_exists("$user.jpg"))
  echo "img src='$user.jpg' border='1' align='left' />";

 $result = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM rnprofiles WHERE user='$user'");

 if (mysql_num_rows($result))
 {
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
  echo stripslashes($row[1]) . "
";
 }
}
?>
```

or is script 2 safer?

```
MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());

  // Print a message to the user, include the footer, and kill the script.
  include ('./includes/footer.htm');
  exit();

 } // End of mysql_select_db IF.

} else { // If it couldn't connect to MySQL.

 // Print a message to the user, include the footer, and kill the script.
 trigger_error("Could not connect to MySQL!\n
MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
 include ('./includes/footer.htm');
 exit();

} // End of $dbc IF.

// Create a function for escaping the data.
function escape_data ($data) {

 // Address Magic Quotes.
 if (ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc')) {
  $data = stripslashes($data);
 }

 // Check for mysql_real_escape_string() support.
 if (function_exists('mysql_real_escape_string')) {
  global $dbc; // Need the connection.
  $data = mysql_real_escape_string (trim($data), $dbc);
 } else {
  $data = mysql_escape_string (trim($data));
 }

 // Return the escaped value. 
 return $data;

} // End of function.
?>
```

Comment: I think this question would be easier to answer if you summarised the differences between the scripts, instead of leaving it to us to wade through some code. I'd be really interested to hear what others say about the code, so please make it easier to decide what the differences are.

Comment: I wonder if any one read through all that code. I didn't!

Comment: Hard/virtually impossible to tell from those arbitrary code snippets of the two scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. Both of them are inconsistent and provide opertunities for unfiltered data to get to the database.

Filtering isn't optional.

There shouldn't be a way to run a query without filtering taking place.
If you're using php 5.2.x, use the [SPL Filter](https://www.php.net/filter) functions to sanitize data.

A data abstraction layer with makes this much easier to do. I like the zend framework's [Zend_Db](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html) and Zend_Db_Table classes. The docs for these have concrete examples which show the best possible usage in action.

Of your two scripts, I'd pick #1. This function-ized code will be much easier to maintain than the stuff in script #2.

Answer (score 0):

Safer way to do that is using MYSQLi or PDO. Also MYSQL_CONNECT and so on is going to disabled in the future versions of php.

Comment: Please don't post link only answers as links may break.